# "SpecNotFound: Invalid name, try the format: user/package" in Creating new Conda env with yml file (Windows 10)

Tags: python, conda, environment

I'm trying to Create New conda environment by **'Anaconda Prompt'** usnig `yml` File in Windows 10.
So here is the **steps** i made through:

**1.** using `cd` command i changed the directory to *dir* which my `yml` file located. (suppose my yml file is in `c:/Users/<USER NAME>/.jupyter` )
**2.** Then i used [`conda env create -f Python 310.yml`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#:%7E:text=conda%20env%20create%20%2Df%20environment.yml) command to create new conda env.

and what i got is:

> SpecNotFound: Invalid name, try the format: user/package

Now I don't know how can I solve this problem and exactly what is the meaning of this error.

---

## Appendix

my `Python 310.yml` file contains these stuff:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

issue solved by changing contents of `Python 310.yml` and renaming `yml` file to `Python310.yml`. Here is the final `.yml` file content:

```py
name: Python3.9 
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - numpy
  - pandas
  - matplotlib
  - pip
  - python=3.9.*      
  - python-dateutil
  - pytz
  - scikit-learn
  - scipy
  - statsmodels
  - xlrd
  - openpyxl
  - lxml
  - html5lib
  - beautifulsoup4
  - jupyter
  - pip:
    - pmdarima        
    - tensorflow
    - keras
prefix: C:\Users\Shayan\Anaconda3\envs\Python3.9
```

Answer (score 36):

drop the "env" in "conda env create" it's just "conda create ..."

Comment: That’s just not true - the `conda create` and `conda env create` commands have different functionality, and only the latter applies to YAML files. The former takes the output of `conda list --export`.

Comment: Based on [the official doc](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file), Your answer isn't the correct one.

Comment: @Shayan could you actually post the correct answer rather than just critiquing?  Alright, let me see... Okay so the docs claim that `conda env create -f environment.yml` is the correct command, but that literally didn't work for the OP.  So try `conda env create -f environment.yml` if you really must, but probably the docs are out of date

Comment: @Nathan, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69483971/11747148) is my answer. It's good to inspect the web pages closely rather than shoot a comment recklessly.

Comment: @Shayan oh, I didn't realize you had also answered that.  Future readers, his answer is helpful

Comment: Although apparently most users just wanted the quick fix of this answer by Chris, so take a look if you're trying to seriously load a `.yml` into your conda env, which apparently most people aren't

Comment: According to the official doc (see Shayan's link) conda env create -f creates an environment from a file, but to create it with a name you use conda create -n (without the "env" in there) which makes no sense but works for me at least.

Answer (score 6):

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71504106/2745495) says to:

> drop the "env" in "conda env create" it's just "conda create ..."

This did not fix it for me by itself, but it did work after trying *that* and then *after that* trying the whole

```
conda env create -n myenv-dev --file my_env.yml
```

command again.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I missed `-f` in the command.

This error message is about trying to parse something as a package name, that is not a package name. In OP's case it was `360.yml` which was taken to be a separate parameter due to the space. In my case it was the whole filename, because I missed `-f`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that the file did not exist. So make sure that the file exists before running the update command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `conda create -f Python 310.yml`.

Comment: I mentioned that in question myself.

Answer (score 0):

##### Make sure your directory is in "quotes", bc I got this error having whitespace inside it...

Answer (score 0):

My solution was because I was running the following command on windows

```
conda env create -n spa --file .\environment.yml
```

and in order to get it to run on my Ubuntu WSL2 just needed a minor update:

```
conda env create -n spa --file environment.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

I put the name of the yml file in double quotes and used the -f= notation and powershell no longer gave me an error. For you, that might mean:

```
conda env create -f="Python 310.yml"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
conda env create -n 'env name' -f environment.yml

Comment: Two other answers already suggest this. Please don't repeat answers.

Comment: I did not see the same, because I tried others but I got into problems. This one worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You just have a typo...check the name of your .yml file... likely you missed something and is not recognized... put your glasses and check ownership of the file also

Comment: what's the typo?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my file name from name.yaml to name.yml and error is gone. Looking at other solutions above, would remocommend renaming the file.